# Count occurrence of numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I am stack for a while. I tried debugging but I couldn't figure out the solution. I am trying to count the occurrence of numbers in ascending order
for example, I have these inputs: 2 5 6 5 4 3 23 43 2
the output I got 
-2 occurs 2 times
-3 occurs one time
-4 occurs one time
-5 occurs 2 times
-6 occurs one time
-43 occurs one time #why this happens?
23 occurs one time

def main():

```
while True:
    try:
        numbers = input("Enter integers between 1 and 100:-")
        #my_list= [int(x) for x in input().split(' ')]
        my_list = list(map(int, numbers.strip().split(' ')))

        break
    except ValueError:
        print ("Oops ! enter an integer... ")
count = {}
for x in set(my_list):
    count[x] = my_list.count(x)
for key, value in count.items():
    if value == 1:
        print('{} occurs one time'.format(key))
    else:
        print('{} occurs {} times'.format(key, value))
```

main ()

Comment: This works fine for me

Comment: the code seems fine..

Comment: Read up on [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) its a specialized dictionary that does the counting part all on its own if you feed it an iterable. Youre erroneous output probably stemms from not copying your code into this question and using a literal '-' in front of your output strings....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output is correct:

Input:

```
2 5 6 5 4 3 23 43 2
```

Output:

```
Enter integers between 1 and 100:-2 5 6 5 4 3 23 43 2
2 occurs 2 times
3 occurs one time
4 occurs one time
5 occurs 2 times
6 occurs one time
43 occurs one time
23 occurs one time
```

Have to sort the dictionary by Keys to get your desired output:

```
import collections
while True:
    try:
        numbers = input("Enter integers between 1 and 100:-")
        #my_list= [int(x) for x in input().split(' ')]
        my_list = list(map(int, numbers.strip().split(' ')))

        break
    except ValueError:
        print ("Oops ! enter an integer... ")
count = {}

for x in set(my_list):
    count[x] = my_list.count(x)
count = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(count.items()))
for key, value in count.items():
    if value == 1:
        print('{} occurs one time'.format(key))
    else:
        print('{} occurs {} times'.format(key, value))
```

below is output:

```
Enter integers between 1 and 100:-23 23 1 2 3 4 5 2 2 4 2 55 55 5 5 55 55 55 55
1 occurs one time
2 occurs 4 times
3 occurs one time
4 occurs 2 times
5 occurs 3 times
23 occurs 2 times
55 occurs 6 times
```

Comment: it should be in ascending order when showing the occurrence

Comment: You means 43, 23, 6,5,4,3,2?

Comment: i mean 2 3 4 5 6 23 43 and each number occurrence

Comment: Updated code above, need to sort the dictionary by keys to achieve your required output. But I also find it strange why 23 always going at end